# Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of reducers always shows 1. I am not able to change it. how can i change it?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using Hive over a hadoop cluster. Whenever I am trying the run a hive query the it always shows as

> Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of reducers: 1

I had used following Hive configuration :

```
hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=1000000000
hive.exec.reducers.max=999
```

please tell me how can of increase the number reducer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set mapred.reduce.tasks parameter?

Comment: no, right now mapred.reduce.tasks is set to "10101010101010101010" and i guess this is a binary number, I did not understand what changes should I make? and what should be the value..

Comment: I changed "mapred.reduce.tasks" from "10101010101010101010" to "101010101010101010", exactly I removed one "10" from the actual number but no effect happend.

Comment: still getting following info :
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 2; number of reducers: 1

Comment: Just try to put mapred.reduce.tasks = 2. Are you working in local mode?

Comment: No, I am on ec2 machine. i tried to change it to different numbers but still it is showing the same result.

Comment: It's weird. You can do it by some artificial way by lowering hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=1000000000 to hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=10000. But I am not quite if it speeds up anything. Keep us posted. GL!

Comment: @ Wawrzyniec : thanks changing the value of "hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer" worked.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have gone through the points given below:

Your mapred.reduce.tasks defaults to -1. By setting this property to -1, Hive will automatically figure out what should be the number of reducers.

A hive query with no grouping will be using only 1 reducer.

And also note that when mapred.job.tracker is "local", hadoop sets mapred.reduce.tasks value to 1 by default.

Comment: thanks Jickson. can I change the the "mapred.job.tracker" to anything else so that I can increase the number of reducer.