# Make cartesian product have more than one reducer in hive

Tags: hive

A simplified version of my query:

```
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.auto.convert.join = false;
set mapred.reduce.tasks=300;

SELECT s.id, w.word
FROM words w JOIN stuff s
WHERE lower(s.text) rlike concat('\\b', w.word, '\\b')
```

What hive 0.13 does:

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 445; number of reducers: 1
```

I think it's using one reducer because there is no ON clause.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15339808/34935.) However, I can't put the "rlike" in the ON clause.

How can I get more reducers checking the WHERE clause?